# Android: Send intent with playable video to telegram app

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send a video to the telegram app via Intent but when I send it, it sends as a file, (same happens with images). Is there any trick to specify how you want to send it? (Because from the gallery it sends the same video playable)

function for sending via Intent

```
private fun shareItem(fileName: String) {
    Log.i(TAG, "shareItem: ")
    val videoContentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(),
        "${activity?.applicationContext?.packageName}.provider",
        File(LocalFilesRepository.getFullVideoPath(fileName, requireContext()))
    )
    Log.i("TAG", "shareItem: $videoContentUri")


    val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        flags =  Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, videoContentUri)
        type = "video/mp4"
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, resources.getText(R.string.send_to)))
}

...
fun getFullVideoPath(fileName: String, context: Context) =
            context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).toString() + File.separatorChar + fileName
```

videoContentUri looks like this content://com.dmytroa.appname.provider/external_files/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dmytroa.appname/files/Movies/1625360538459.mp4

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interested I solved it by just saving a file temporarily at the public storage and then returning Uri from Mediastore.

```
fun createTemporaryCopyInPublicStorage(file: File, context: Context): Uri? {
            val fileName = "tmp"
            return if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
                val uri = findCreatedTemporaryUri(context, fileName, TEMPORARY_DIR_Q)
                copyVideoQAndAbove(context, file, uri, fileName, TEMPORARY_DIR_Q)
            } else {
                val uri = findCreatedTemporaryUri(context, fileName, TEMPORARY_DIR_BELOWQ)
                copyVideoBelowQ(context, file, uri, fileName, TEMPORARY_DIR_BELOWQ)
            }
        }


        private fun findCreatedTemporaryUri(context: Context, fileName: String, path: String): Uri? {
            val collection = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
                MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
            } else {
                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            }

            val selection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
                "${MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE} = ? " +
                        "AND " +
                        "${MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH} = ? "
            } else {
                "${MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE} = ? " +
                        "AND " +
                        "${MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA} = ? "
            }

            val args = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
                arrayOf(fileName, path)
            } else {
                arrayOf(fileName, File(path, fileName).absolutePath)
            }

            context.contentResolver.query(
                collection,
                arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID
                ),
                selection,
                args,
                null
            ).use { cursor ->
                return if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    val columnIndexID = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)
                    val id = cursor.getLong(columnIndexID)

                    Log.i(TAG, "findCreatedTemporaryUri: " +
                            "contentUri was already added $id $path $fileName")
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "$id")
                } else {
                    null
                }
            }
        }

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        private fun copyVideoQAndAbove(context: Context,
                                       fileToCopy: File,
                                       uri: Uri?,
                                       fileName: String,
                                       relPath: String): Uri? {

            val contentDetails = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
            }

            val contentUri = if (uri != null) {
                context.contentResolver.update(uri, contentDetails, null, null)
                uri
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "saveVideoQAndAbove: contentUri insert")
                contentDetails.apply {
                    put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
                    put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
                    put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, relPath)
                }
                val collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
                context.contentResolver.insert(collection, contentDetails)
            }

            return contentUri?.let { createdUri ->
                try {
                    context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(createdUri, "w").use { pfd ->
                        ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(pfd).write(fileToCopy.readBytes())
                    }
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                contentDetails.clear()
                contentDetails.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
                context.contentResolver.update(createdUri, contentDetails, null, null)
                createdUri
            }
        }

        private fun copyVideoBelowQ(context: Context,
                                    fileToCopy: File,
                                    uri: Uri?,
                                    fileName: String,
                                    dstParentPath: String): Uri? {
            val dstDir = File(dstParentPath)
            if (!dstDir.exists())
                dstDir.mkdirs()

            val fileToCreate = File(dstDir, fileName)

            fileToCreate.delete()
            fileToCreate.createNewFile()
            Log.i(TAG, "saveVideo: created ${fileToCreate.name}")
            try {
                fileToCopy.inputStream().use { input ->
                    fileToCreate.outputStream().use { output ->
                        input.copyTo(output, 2 * 1024)
                        Log.i(TAG, "saveVideo: finished ${fileToCreate.path}")
                    }
                }
                return uri ?: let {
                    val values = ContentValues().apply {
                        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, fileToCreate.name)
                        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
                        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, fileToCreate.path)
                    }
                    context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            return null
        }

        private val TEMPORARY_DIR_Q = Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES + File.separator +
                "APPNAME" + File.separator +
                "temporary" + File.separator

        private val TEMPORARY_DIR_BELOWQ = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).absolutePath + File.separator +
                "APPNAME" + File.separator +
                "temporary" + File.separator
```